# C# creating a relationship between two iLists

Tags: c#

I'm trying to fetch a name from one iList into another where they both contain the same ID.

```
    public class Notifications 
{

    [JsonProperty("note_id")]
   public int note_id { get; set;}
    [JsonProperty("sender_id")]
    public int sender_id { get; set;}
    public string sender_name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("receiver_id")]
    public int receiver_id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("document_id")]
    public int document_id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("search_name")]
    public string search_name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("unread")]
    public int unread { get; set; }
}
public class CompanyDirectory
{

    [JsonProperty("contact_id")]
    public int contact_id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("second_name")]
    public string second_name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("extension")]
    public string extension { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("direct_dial")]
    public string direct_dial { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("job_title")]
    public string job_title { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("company_id")]
    public int company_id { get; set; }

}
```

Then i'm doing the following, the lists both get populated fine. The weird bit is i'm getting errors saying that where I do CompanyDir.first_name that the property doesn't exist, where it clearly does?:

```
// This occurs just after the class declaration
public IList<Notifications> Notes;
public IList<CompanyDirectory> CompanyDir;

// Ignore that these both use the same string they're created at different parts of the load process
CompanyDir = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<CompanyDirectory>>(responseString);
Notes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Notifications>>(responseString);

// Now I thought I should be able to do
foreach(var s in Notes){
  var thename = CompanyDir.first_name.Where(contact_id.Contains(s.sender_id))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look up LinQ and Lambda expressions:

```
var firstNames = CompanyDir.Where(c => c.contact_id == s.sender_id)
                           .Select(c => c.first_name)
                           .ToList();
```

Now you have a list of firstnames. A list, because there may be zero or more hits for your Where constraint.

Comment: Hmm there should be one entry in CompanyDir per ID, if I change ToList to ToString I don't get first_name I get System.Linq.Enumerable in the Notes.name field